Converting WinCC Ticks to C# DateTime and vice versa
When you save the log files of Siemens WinCC Flexible as text files, you will have one field as Date and time, and another field as Ticks:



TimeString
Time_ms




"2024-03-16 00:38:20"
45367026614.6759


"2024-10-30 17:17:54"
45595720764.7685



Since the date and time field does not show the milliseconds, I needed to use the other field to get the value.
After some challenges, I figured out that Siemens uses the date December 30th, 1899 as the Start date. I don't know how they came up with this date.
I was finally able to convert the Ticks to date and time.
Now my question is regarding the conversion of a date and time to this kind of tick.
The goal is converting the fields of this table to each other.
Does anyone know a solution?
As far as I know, my problem is in the "DateTimeToSiemensTime" function.
This is what I've done:
double mainTick = 45590722754.8727; //"2024-10-25 17:20:46", as shown in log file
DateTime dt = SiemensTimeToDateTime(mainTick);
double calcTick = DateTimeToSiemensTime(dt);
double diff = calcTick - mainTick; //Goal: This should be zero but it isn't!

DateTime SiemensTimeToDateTime(double siemensTime)
{
    // Julian Date (JD): Jan 1st, 1900
    // Dublin Julian Date (DJD): Dec 31st, 1899
    // Siemens: Dec 30th, 1899 --- WHY??!!!!!

    // Start with new date object as Dec 30th, 1899.
    // Divide siemensTime by 1000000 to get the number of Days.

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
    return startDateTime.AddDays(siemensTime / 1_000_000d);
}

double DateTimeToSiemensTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan ts = dateTime.Subtract(startDateTime);
    return (double)(ts.Ticks) / 1_000_000d;
}


It looks like you've got an implementation - so what's not working? Can you give a concrete example of input, expected output and actual output? (I'd also strongly advise you to start following .NET naming conventions, but that's a different matter.)

@JonSkeet Thanks, I hope the question seems clearer now.

I don't know how they came up with this date. they use the same base date as Excel, which in turn used the same base as Lotus 1-2-3, the most popular spreadsheet in the early1990s. The integer part is supposed to be days though, And needless to say, Siemens didn't need compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3. Maybe, the huge integer is used to avoid rounding errors, so you're supposed to divide by 1M before using DateTime.FromOADate to convert? It may well be that even Siemens doesn't know why that format was used

@JonSkeet my guess - old software/hardware that chose OADate multiplied by 1M for storage in 32-bit registers, because 32-bit ints can't store millisecond timestamps and 32-bit floats would result in significant rounding errors.

By subtracting the two numbers we can figure out that the difference is
228694150,09259796   Time_ms intervals
228.16:39:34         Days

This tells us that the Siemens time seems to use 1'000'000 intervals per day. So your method SiemensTimeToDateTime() seems already correct.
However, the inverse function needs to be based on days as well, not ticks, so:
double DateTimeToSiemensTime(DateTime dateTime)
{
    DateTime winccEpoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
    TimeSpan ts = dateTime.Subtract(winccEpoch);
    return ts.TotalDays * 1_000_000.0;
}

For type safety, you might want to introduce a WinccTime class, so you never lose the type information of the double.
public class WinccTime
{
    private static readonly DateTime winCCEpoch = new DateTime(1899, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0);
    private double _winccIntervals;
    public WinccTime(double winccIntervals)
    {
        _winccIntervals = winccIntervals;
    }
    public WinccTime(DateTime dateTime)
    {
       _winccIntervals = dateTime.Subtract(winCCEpoch).TotalDays * 1_000_000.0;
    }
    public DateTime ToDateTime()
    {   
        return winCCEpoch.AddDays(_winccIntervals / 1_000_000);
    }
    public double ToWinccIntervals()
    {   
        return _winccIntervals;
    }
}


Dividing the number by 1M produces a valid OADate.

That's an OADate value multiplied by 1M. Possibly to avoid rounding errors when stored as a 32-bit floating point number.
You can use the DateTime.FromOADate to convert the value to a DateTime after dividing by 1M:
var date=DateTime.FromOADate(x/1_000_000);

Console.WriteLine(${date:o}");

This prints
 2024-03-16T00:38:19.5080000 

OADate or OLE Automation Date is a format that was used by Lotus 1-2-3, the most popular spreadsheet at the time. Excel copied this for obvious reasons, and then that was used in Access and Windows' OLE Automation (hence the OA).
As for why that was used instead of eg a Unix timestamp with microsecond precision .... only guesses. Maybe the software, or the libraries it's based on, was so old they wanted to be compatible with Lotus 1-2-3? Maybe they decided to just replicate Excel without considering alternatives? Maybe they wanted to use Excel's format for "reasons" but store the actual value in a float instead of double?
Perhaps, way back when the software was made, they could only use 32-bit CPU registers or storage, with meant that a Unix timestamp with millisecond precision couldn't be used?
Console.WriteLine("{0:o}",DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeMilliseconds(int.MaxValue));

shows 32-bits are definitely inadequate
 1970-01-25T20:31:23.6470000+00:00 

And perhaps using a 32-bit float would cause significant errors, perhaps even flipping the order of events?
